# Do I need to clear out all the Reaper code in Rannoch: Geth Fighter Squadrons?

Tags: mass-effect-3

During this mission, you're sent into a sort of virtual world. You can clear out Reaper code inside the Geth server by shooting it with your weapon.

[image: code]

In the same vein of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54884/is-there-any-benefit-to-destroying-all-the-spore-and-gestation-pods), I'm wondering the following. My OCD-tendencies have me shooting away *every last orange cube possible*, but in the interest of time (and sanity), can I stick to just clearing out the code that's directly in my path? Will I be at any sort of disadvantage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will be at no disadvantage other than your OCD will be screaming at you for not clearing every last bit.

Regardless of how much you clear, the end goal remains unaltered: Reach the data cores and  **completely** rid them of their viruses.

Whether it's "just enough" or "Reaper virus dead to the last", it makes no difference in dialogue or story. Which means I wasted a solid hour in there for no reason.

Comment: I am sad to say I cleared out every bit and wouldn't leave until I did so.

Comment: You *do* have to clear all the glowing orange bits off the "data spheres," which confused me to no end - I thought just severing the connections was enough.

Comment: Should also note that they very, very slowly grow back as well.

Answer (score 1):

Na you should be fine if you don't clear all the code out. It's really getting to the data clusters that is important.